# Calculate between date/time when weekend in between

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, excel-formula, weekday

I have a true false result calculation based on obtaining data between 12pm one day and 12pm the next day.
In cell S2, I have: =TODAY()-1 +12/24
In cell S3, I have: =S2+1 -1/1440

This give me a simple true or false in my 'helper' column Q :
=AND(G2>=$S$2,G2<=$S$3)

This all works perfectly for me as I extract this data to do other things - BUT, I have a problem in that stupid me forgot about weekends!

So, when look at my data on a Monday afternoon, I get nothing from Friday afternoon (after 12pm) because of course it is much greater than my calculation

I 'think' I can achieve this somehow using IF statement and WEEKDAY equation, but despite trying different examples, I can't get it to work.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction here?

Comment: `=WORKDAY.INTL(TODAY(),-1)+0.5` and `=WORDKDAY.INTL(S2,1)+0.5-1/1440` You can even add a list of holidays to skip.

Comment: Thank you Scott.  I have put =WORKDAY.INTL(TODAY(),-1)+0.5 into Cell S2 and that looks OK.  I then have put =WORDKDAY.INTL(S2,1)+0.5-1/1440 into Cell s3 , however that comes back with a #NAME? error.  Do I have a typo somewhere please?

Comment: yes there is a typo in the second: `=WORKDAY.INTL(S2,1)+0.5-1/1440`

Comment: thank you Scott - that now is locked in, so will see how it goes on Monday.

Comment: Oh, and I meant to ask - how would I add a list of holidays to this please Scott?  I have a spreadsheet with what these days are and when they fall in a calendar year - would I do a vlookup to that area?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/workday-intl-function-a378391c-9ba7-4678-8a39-39611a9bf81d

Answer (score 0):

Would [Column I ] ...greater than, less than formula - help?

[image]

Note: Column D  ...has a "Zero" (0) for the weekends - but you can adjust the formula to be whatever you want.

Comment: Hi Jayson,   Thanks for that input.  That may also do the trick .  The reason for this code is that we use a 'book out' spreadsheet to monitor items issued each day.  This information is then transferred to SAP once a day.  To annotate what information needs to go into SAP - we have to work out which line was last entered.  We used to simply just highlight the last line for the day shift (that finishes at 12pm) and next day, copy the information between the two highlight lines and paste all that information into excel.  Hence the code above to just give me 24 hours worth.

Answer (score -2):

`=WORKDAY.INTL(TODAY(),-1)+0.5` and `=WORKDAY.INTL(S2,1)+0.5-1/1440` You can even add a list of holidays to skip. –
`Scott Craner`